# Could not locate gemfile in termux app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

When i'm trying to install bundle with this command "bundle install" then it is showing me

> could not locate gemfile

Please help me!!!!

[here is the screenshort see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOeHJ.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have installed Bundler with `bundler -v`. If you don't have it, install it with `gem install bundler`.

Later, create a new gemfile with `bundle init` command.

Answer (score 0):

To work, you need to have a file name **Gemfile** with a list of all gem required by your application.

Locate this file and run the command in the same directory.